# What happens when two Reinhardts charge each other when one is Zarya bubbled

Tags: overwatch

If two Reinhardts charge at each other normally they both fall to the ground. What happens if one is Zarya bubbled? Does it prevent them from being knocked?

How does this interact with Doomfist punch and Brigette Shield Bash?

Comment: From my experience I recall that they still cancel and get knocked down, don't know if damage is taken but whichever one is shielded wouldn't take damage. The same happens when a Zarya saves anyone from a charge by shielding you right before you get pinned.

Answer (score 7):

Zarya's barrier doesn't prevent knockbacks from melee attacks. In your scenario, the bubble would make no difference and would still result in both Reinhardt being knocked down.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure about that ? 
As Lucio, I can't boop people being bubbled.

Comment: @AzirisMorora That's not a melee attack.

Comment: Oh, right ! Sorry !

Comment: Does the Zarya bubble block Shield Bash now?  I know the 4 true shields (Rein, Brig, Winston, and Orisa) all block it now.

Comment: @MBraedley That has nothing to do with my answer.

Comment: "How does this interact with Doomfist punch and Brigette Shield Bash?" Which is exactly what I was asking you to clarify.